# How to register broadcast receiver once it is unregister after app is killed

Tags: android

Hi I am working on android app where I am looking to register broadcast receiver automatically once system close all services & unregister broadcast receiver once it is killed in Xiomi.

I want something like that once broadcast receiver is killed then it will auto register as like we can do in service with `start_sticky` flag.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Xiaomi, but for all Android devices, this should solve the problem :-
Import this :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
```

This code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
intent.setAction("com.example.Broadcast");
intent.putExtra("MyData", 1000);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Remember to include "intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);"

Hope this helps ! :)

Comment: Try this : `<application
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
   <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
   
      <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED">
         </action>
      </intent-filter>
   
   </receiver>
</application>`

Comment: this is for reboot. I asked something different. could you please read my question

Comment: After reboot, the device unregisters the Broadcast Activity. To register it you have to do this in Manifest. Isn't it something you asked for ?

Comment: No problem. I asked that in xiomi when i killed app then it unregister receiver and stop services etc. In my app , registering notification receiver in androidmanifest so how i auto register in androidmanifest